# What is an efficient way to read and store input data from multiple files in python?

Tags: python, database, time-series, pytorch

I want to train a classifier for 8000 data samples in python (using sklearn or pytorch libraries). But, each data is a times-series stored in a .wav file.

Do I have to first read all 8000 files in a loop and store them in a big file, and read that big file each time I want to train a classifier? or there is a more efficient way for such cases?

Comment: Do you have some code already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to have one big file. 
At some point you may lack the GPU memory (memory overall).
What you need is lazy loading.

In PyTorch you have the [`Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) and [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) classes.

Dataset just need to implement two methods.

```
class Dataset(object):

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __len__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

`DataLoader` class is there to provide you the single batch of data. If batch size is 64  (bs=64) this means 64 .wav files from once. So you will instruct the `DataLoader` to load bs of data from once. This is lazy loading.